# Refactoring type code override

Tags: java, refactoring, hierarchy

There's a piece of code I'm currently looking like which serialises/deserialises data.

The class structure looks something like this:

```
public class Field
{
    public abstract void writeField(DataOutputStream out);

    public abstract int getFieldID();

    ...

    protected static final int INT_FIELD = 1;
    protected static final int BOOL_FIELD = 2;

    ...

    public void write(DataOutputStream out)
    {
        out.writeInt(getFieldID());
        writeField(out);
    }

    ...
}

public class IntField extends Field
{
    public int v;

    public void writeField(DataOutputStream out)
    {
        out.writeInt(v);
    }

    public int getFieldID()
    {
        return Field.INT_FIELD;
    }
}
```

I feel like the way getFieldID is implemented is not the best.

Writing an abstract method to return a unique identifier for that class feels like a bad smell.

Is there better ways to go about implementing this?

Comment: See my answer if it's what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listing subclass-specific constants in a base class is not that great an idea, because ideally a superclass should not know about its subclasses. Just listing the constants in the base is not as bad as *using* them to differentiate among subclasses in the code of the base class.

Ideally, you should move the constants into their respective subclasses. If you cannot do it without breaking a compile, you've indeed stumbled upon a prime candidate for refactoring.

Comment: I guess the issue with that is that you could run into fields IDs that would clash. Because there isn't a centralised list of field IDs you could end up declaring the field ID as the same in two separate subclasses.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a class with Generics.
Like this:

Field

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

public abstract class Field<T extends Object> {
    public abstract void writeField(DataOutputStream out);
    public abstract T getValue();
    public abstract Class<T> getFieldClass();
}
```

IntField

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class IntField extends Field<Integer> {
    public Integer v;

    @Override
    public void writeField(DataOutputStream out) {
        try {
            out.writeChars(v.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Integer> getFieldClass() {
        return Integer.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: When reading the data back from the file, how do you determine what object to create in order to read in the right information? There's no identifying information in the file, correct?

Comment: You can define the structure yourself to identify the type of file. :)

Answer (score 1):

other than using implementation inheritance using super class abstract method which is overridden in the subclass can make the classes tightly coupled.

You can have an interface which is implemented in to an implementation class where all the methods declared in the interface is implemented in the implementation class. This method yest another flavor of inheritance is known as interface inheritance. This reduces the tight coupling in between the super class and sub class.